# Why are the parameters to my C++ function filled with garbage?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, undefined-behavior

I am currently attempting to write a small program in C++ to learn a specific feature of OpenGl (Transform feedback). I have a small function that is part of this program that is supposed to load a shader and provide a GLuint to the user of that function.

Function in header:

```
namespace glutils{

   GLuint loadShader(const std::string &path, GLenum type);

}
```

Function implementation:

```
GLuint glutils::loadShader(const std::string &path, GLenum type) {
    GLuint shader = glCreateShader(type);

    std::string shaderSource = utils::loadFile(path);
    const char *shaderSourceCString = shaderSource.c_str();
    glShaderSource(shader, 1, &shaderSourceCString, nullptr);

    glCompileShader(shader);

    GLint success;
    glGetShaderiv(shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if(!success){
        GLchar infoLog[1024];
        glGetShaderInfoLog(shader, 1024, nullptr, infoLog);
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to compile shader " + path + ":\n" + infoLog);
    }

    return shader;
}
```

Function use:

```
GLuint shader = glutils::loadShader("sqrt.glsl", GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
```

When I first ran my program, it was crashing with a segmentation fault. I used my debugger (LLDB wrapper in CLion) to determine where it is. It is the call to `glCreateShader` on the second line of my function. My debugger also told me that the parameter `path` is a string full of garbage, and that the parameter `type` contains a value different than that of `GL_VERTEX_SHADER`. When looking at the function, I noticed that I had initially forgotten to add a return to the end, which is undefined behavior and thus can cause this. Correcting this error, however, did not fix the garbage data arguments and associated segmentation fault. I tried searching for similar issues with my preferred search engine to no avail.

What is the issue? How can I fix it?

Comment: Your code is incomplete and it is likely that the origin of your memory corruption is not in the part of your code that you have shown.

Comment: Are you calling this function from the thread that has OpenGL context?
Otherwise, seems like you've corrupted memory somewhere before this call.

Comment: @Podgorskiy My program is single threaded. I am not aware of any memory corruption taking place. Because this OpenGl program is designed to be used in a GPGPU context, it does not create a window. The entirety of the code before the call to `glutils::loadShader` is simply creating a context with SFML, in the same way I have in other headless programs without issue.

Comment: @Marcel How should I provide the full source code? The program is a bit large IMO to go directly in the question, although that would work if there is no better way.

Comment: @john01dav, is it that function the first call of OpenGL API? Could you please call any other OpenGL function before `loadShader`? Just to make sure, that context is created properly. Creating OpenGL context in headless mode was always tricky.

Comment: @Podgorskiy Your commend made me realize another issue with the code. I forgot to tell glad to load the opengl functions. Correcting that prevents a segmentation fault on glCreateShader, but the parameters are still garbage. The context is created with the creation of an sf::Context object on the stack. The documentation for the constructor of this class is "The constructor creates and activates the context ". The context is created identically to other, working, code.

Comment: @Podgorskiy I accidently misread your comment initially. I thought you were asking if it was the first call, rather than asking me to add another call. Placing my VAO initialization before shader loading shows that OpenGl is initialized properly as the VAO calls have no errors.

Comment: @john01dav, so there is no segfault anymore, but parameters are still garbage, right? Maybe it's CLion issue not showing them correctly? Have you tried printf them? If they are indeed garbage, then please post at least code that creates parameters to be passed and invokes `glutils::loadShader`.

Comment: @Podgorskiy It is a clion error, or, rather, 2. It was running the program in the wrong directory (it doesn't set it to any default for some reason, and I have no idea where it was running, so technically not a bug), and the debugger was giving me inaccurate values of the string. I shall report this to Jetbrains. Thank you for your help :).

Comment: @john01dav, You are welcome!

Comment: Try changing `const std::string &path` to `const std::string path` and see if you still get garbage in your path.